# By closing a socket after only reading the useful data, am I really saving bandwidth?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, stream

I mean, I have an app that in a first step only needs to get the size of some images in a webserver, to do that, I'm using fsockopen. After reading the `content-length` header, I close the socket.

The question may be silly but I know little to nothing about the tcp protocol and the whole data transmision process over the internet and how the file gets to my php app throught this socket, so what I want to know is: Am I saving bandwidth by closing the socket before reading the whole file or is it still transferred to my local machine in it's entirety anyway? What about the server that hosts the image, does it know the socket is closed and stops sending the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on a bunch of stuff.  If the image is 10 Terabytes, then yes.  Absolutely.  If it's 100k, then probably not.

It all has to do with buffers -- buffers all over the place.  Buffers on each computer, on each device in the network between them.. as well as latency and available bandwidth.

But basically if the file is big, yes, you're saving bandwidth.  If it's small, you're not.  Figuring out exactly would be difficult and the number of variables involved would be large. And the break-even point would likely change over time unless you controlled the full end-to-end system (and even then lots of things you would have a hard time controlling would still impact the answer).

Comment: Ok, got it! In my case I'll go with the head request as EJP said, which solves my problem, but this answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to mention that, but forgot.  Glad you got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes, for large enough files, but you'd save a lot more if you used the HTTP HEAD request for this, not a full GET request. Then you would save for all files.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I didn't really know about this type of request. It's perfect for my app. I've chosen xaxxon's answer as correct since it targets the question I had, even though I wouldn't ask it if I knew about this head request beforehand :)